# How to translate wacky metadata to readable format?

Tags: windows, metadata, winamp

This is a song metadata i have (on Winamp):

[image]

I'm trying to figure which artist it really is. Tried googling/google translate, but couldn't find the artist/title in english. Although, one page showed the name "Wagner" in there, but I listened many of his songs but didn't find it.

How can I decode it into readable format; in that language it was written in (using unicode perhaps?), so i can use google translate to translate it? Or do i actually need to know the language before doing so?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by character encoding mismatch, which is fairly common when legacy 8-bit encodings are used. A broken tagger marked the ID3 tag as being ISO-8859-1, but actually encoded the text in Windows-1251 (which ID3v2 does not allow). Your player doesn't know about it and thinks that the text is in ISO-8859-1. Or maybe worse; it also ignores the ID3 spec and thinks the tag is in Windows-1252 or whatever your local encoding is. Wikipedia calls this [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake).

(It's impossible for a program to reliably differentiate between the 8-bit Windows-125x or ISO-8859-x encodings other than by making statistical guesses based on letter frequencies as the Universal Decoder does, so the encoding has to be specified explicitly. The ID3v1 specification only allowed ISO-8859-1, but nobody cared about it. ID3v2 allows ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, and UTF-16, with the encoding being specified in the tag itself. Unfortunately, not all players have started caring.)

The [Universal Cyrillic Decoder](http://2cyr.com/decode/) might help; it decodes "Artist" to **[Евгений Мравинский](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9,_%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)**.

If the page doesn't work, try [this tool](http://nullroute.eu.org/~grawity/misc/fixcharset.php) or find a Linux box that has `iconv`:

```
echo "garbage" | iconv -t Windows-1252 | iconv -f Windows-1251
```

(Hopefully, Winamp will know better and store the fixed tags in Unicode...)

**Do not use ID3 version 1 when tagging music, to (mostly) avoid such problems.**

Comment: It's a long shot, but MP3Tag (http://www.mp3tag.de/en/) may be able to fix the character encoding mismatch. There isn't much it cannot do.

Comment: Excellent website! Did the job perfectly.

Comment: When I try the same; `echo 'c2 8d 44 e2 80 99 c2 b2 c2 8d 44 e2 80 99 c2 b2' | xxd -p -r | iconv -f utf8 -t sjis ; echo`
I get an error; `iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0`